# Unable to deploy node image(NestJS) on AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

I am literally new with AWS as well and Containerization technology. What I am trying to achieve is that deploying a node image to AWS.

AS I am working with NESTJS my `main.ts` bootstrap method

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1');
  await app.listen(5000);
  Logger.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`, "Bootstrap");
}
bootstrap();
```

I am also using `Travis CI` to ship my container to AWS

My `Docker` file

```
# Download base image
FROM node:alpine as builder

# Define Base Directory
WORKDIR /usr/app/Api

# Copy and restore packages
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy all other directories
COPY ./ ./

# Setup base command
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

MY `.travis.yml` file --> which is the config of Travis CI

```
sudo: required
services:
    - docker

branches:
    only: 
        - master

before_install:
    - docker build -t xx/api .

script:
    - docker run xx/api npm run test

deploy:
    provider: elasticbeanstalk
    region: "us-east-2"
    app: "api"
    env: "api-env"
    bucket_name: "name"
    bucket_path: "api"
    on:
        branch: master
    access_key_id: "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
    secret_access_key: "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"
```

Every time code pushed from Travis CI my Elastic beanstalk start building and failed.

So, I start googling to solve the issue. What I could is that I need to expose port using NGINX. [Expost 80 PORT](https://alligator.io/workflow/deploying-docker-app/)

```
FROM Nginx 
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My question is how should I incorporate NGINX to my docker file? AS my application is not something `static content`. If I move all my build artefacts to `/usr/share/nginx/html`. This will simply not work as I am not serving static content. So What I need is that I simultaneously run my server to server node app as well as run another container with NGINX which will export 80 port and proxy my requests.

How should I do that? Any help?

[image: My AWS Elastic beanstalk failure image]

Comment: You don't need Nginx for your use case. The tutorial was using Nginx because it was serving frontend app without a server so it needed Nginx server to server the static files. Your app is a backend from what I see. What's the start script in your package.json?

Comment: Try adding `EXPOSE 5000` before `CMD` in your Dockerfile